# HIVE regexp_extract URL strings

Tags: regex, hive

Hi I'm trying to parse large URL's from a log using Hive.

There is a particular value that I want to extract from the URL (strategy=??) the values can be hyphenated, but not always.

I built this sample query, but it just returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

```
select regexp_extract('234=23234&werw=asdf&strategy=retargeting&asdf=fds23', '(strategy=)([-\w*]*)',2) from vt;
```

so the value I'm expecting to get is **retargeting** from this partial URL string. 
234=23234&werw=asdf&strategy=**retargeting**&asdf=fds23

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What are you getting now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this regex will work for you:

`strategy=((\w-?)+)`

Here's a RegExr link: http://regexr.com?35sbl. After matching, group 1 contains the value of `strategy`. Note that this regex will match any number of hyphens in the value. It also fails if the hyphen is the first character (though, in my opinion, a leading hyphen does not make a value 'hyphenated').

From what I can tell, your method didn't return anything because of the way group 2 is set up: you have `[-\w*]`, which says "match a hyphen and then any number of alphanumeric characters (including 0)". You could also rewrite this as `[-?\w*]*`, which says "match or don't match a hyphen, and then any number of alphanumeric characters (including 0)". However, this would then match **just** a hyphen, as in this case

`strategy=-`

Which is not something you want, I would think. A slightly safer way might be setting group 2 to `[-?\w+]+`, which would require at least one `\w` character after the equals sign. Happy coding! :)

Comment: You steered me in the right direction. However, had to change it quite a bit for hive. 


Because it's a URL, Hive has parse_url() so, this is what I ended up doing. 

    select parse_url(url, 'QUERY', 'strategy') from amp_server limit 10;

but this also works too. 

    select regexp_replace(url, '.*strategy=([^&]+).*','\$1') from amp_server limit 10;

Comment: That sounds like a much better way to handle it, thanks for accepting my answer though!